# twisted on centos missing mail.smtp?

Tags: python, twisted, centos, rpm

I'm trying to get buildbot running on centos5, and getting the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/buildbot/status/mail.py", line 14, in ?
    from twisted.mail.smtp import sendmail, ESMTPSenderFactory
ImportError: No module named mail.smtp
```

I have the following twisted packages installed (and don't see anything else relevant to install):

```
$ rpm -qa | grep twisted
python-twisted-web-0.7.0-1.el5
python-twisted-core-2.5.0-4.el5
python-twisted-words-0.5.0-3.el5
```

I'm more familiar with debian where I can do:

```
$ apt-file find twisted/mail/smtp
python-twisted-mail: /usr/share/pyshared/twisted/mail/smtp.py
```

Two questions:

1. Is there something I can pull from yum that will provide this file or do I need to resort to manual tactics for this part of twisted?
2. Is there anything analogous to the `apt-file` command above for rpm/yum-based systems?

Thanks.

(I considered superuser, but this seems so tightly coupled to programming that I expect better answers here...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of apt-file in redhat is "yum whatprovides". But I did try this for the smtp package you are looking for and it did return any matching package :(

```
[vc@vc ~]$ yum whatprovides */twisted/mail/smtp.py 
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror 
Excluding Packages in global exclude list 
Finished 
addons/filelists                       |  195 B     00:00      
base/filelists_db                      | 3.4 MB     00:01      
extras/filelists_db                    | 197 kB     00:00      
updates/filelists_db                   | 2.9 MB     00:01      
No Matches found
```

This link has a [comparison about different package managers](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta), hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, the tip on whatprovides is helpful.